# GroovyClassLoader call to parseClass is successful, even when code does not compile

Tags: java, groovy, classloader, groovyclassloader

I'm trying to dynamically load a Groovy script as a class but the class object is created even when the script's code does not compile.

For example, a simplified version of my Groovy code to load the Groovy script is as follows:

```
GroovyCodeSource src = new GroovyCodeSource(
    "blah blah blah",
    "Foo.groovy",
    GroovyShell.DEFAULT_CODE_BASE
)
new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(src, true)
```

Clearly, the code `blah blah blah` isn't a legitimate Groovy script. And yet, a class object is successfully created for this dynamic code. According to [GroovyClassLoader's Javadoc for the `parseClass` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#parseClass(groovy.lang.GroovyCodeSource,boolean)) a `CompilationFailedException` should be thrown for cases such as this.

How is it possible that the class is still created for broken code and how can I successfully create a class from dynamic Groovy source code conditionally on whether or not the code will compile? I've done a lot of research and experimentation but to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because groovy provides dynamic access to methods and properties and in terms of Groovy, the code `blah blah blah`, is valid. Actually you are providing code for Script (there is no class declaration). After compilation, you will get a class that extends [groovy.lang.Script](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html).

So, let me continue your code and show you how it could be valid...

```
GroovyCodeSource src = new GroovyCodeSource(
    'blah blah blah',
    "Foo.groovy",
    GroovyShell.DEFAULT_CODE_BASE
)
def c = new GroovyClassLoader().parseClass(src, true)
println c                     //class Foo
println c.getSuperclass()     //class groovy.lang.Script

def i = c.newInstance()
//i.run()                     //MissingPropertyException: No such property: blah for class: Foo
i.setBinding([
    blah: { x-> return [blah: "x.class =${x.getClass()}"] }
] as Binding)
i.run()                       //SUCCESS
```

I would also advise you to run `groovyconsole`, enter `blah blah blah`, press <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>, and check what class was generated for your script. Note that you could switch between different compilation/parsing phases.
[image]

---

A possible workaround is to use the `CompileStatic` annotation on the methods or the class:

```
//compilation of this code will fail with message
//[Static type checking] - The variable [blah] is undeclared.
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
def f(){
    blah blah blah
}
f()
```

---

You could force `GroovyClassLoader` to make static validation for the whole script.

Let's imagine you want your scripts to access only some pre-defined variables/methods and you want to check this at compile step and not at runtime.

The following example shows how to do that and it will fail the `blah blah blah` code during compilation:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.customizers.builder.CompilerCustomizationBuilder
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

//your base Script class that declares only valid members
//for example `log`
abstract class MyScript extends groovy.lang.Script{
    PrintStream log
}

//create compiler config with base script class 
CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration()
cc.setScriptBaseClass(MyScript.class.getName())
//make static compilation set for class loader
cc = CompilerCustomizationBuilder.withConfig(cc){ 
    ast(CompileStatic) 
}
//create classloader with compile config
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader(),cc)


GroovyCodeSource src = new GroovyCodeSource(
    "log.println 'hello world'",
    "Foo.groovy",
    GroovyShell.DEFAULT_CODE_BASE
)
def c = gcl.parseClass(src, true)  //this will fail for 'blah blah blah' source
def i = c.newInstance(log:System.out)
i.run()
```

P.S. There are other code transformers available in Groovy.

Comment: added compile static for the whole script example

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you so much for the detailed education. For me, the life-saver was the `CompileStatic` AST transformer.